# Always Incorrect username or password.- Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've installed Yii2 advanced app, I customized the signup according to my user database. After signing up I tried to log in and it says `"Incorrect username or password"`, my password is qwerty also I've checked it many times and it still does not work.

[image: User Table]

[image: As you can see here, the user information after signing up it records the data to the user table.]

The signup model

```
class SignupForm extends Model
{
public $username;
public $email;
public $password;
public $first_name;
public $middle_name;
public $last_name;
public $contact;
public $birth_date;
public $type;
public $external_type;
public $status;
public $region_id;
public $barangay_id;
public $province_id;
public $city_municipal_id;


/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['username', 'trim'],
        ['username', 'required'],
        ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
        ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],

        ['email', 'trim'],
        ['email', 'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        ['email', 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],

        ['password', 'required'],
        ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],

        ['first_name', 'required'],
        ['first_name', 'string', 'max' => 45],

        ['middle_name', 'string', 'max' => 45],

        ['last_name', 'required'],
        ['last_name', 'string', 'max' => 45],

        ['contact', 'required'],
        ['contact', 'string', 'max' => 11],

        ['birth_date', 'required'],

        ['type', 'required'],
        ['type', 'string', 'max' => 45],

        ['external_type', 'string', 'max' => 45],

        ['status', 'string', 'max' => 45],

        ['region_id', 'required'],
        ['barangay_id', 'required'],
        ['province_id', 'required'],
        ['city_municipal_id', 'required'],
    ];
}

/**
 * Signs user up.
 *
 * @return User|null the saved model or null if saving fails
 */
public function signup()
{
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return null;
    }

    $user = new User();
    $user->username = $this->username;
    $user->email = $this->email;
    $user->setPassword($this->password);
    $user->generateAuthKey();

    $user->first_name = $this->first_name;
    $user->middle_name = $this->middle_name;
    $user->last_name = $this->last_name;
    $user->contact = $this->contact;
    $user->birth_date = $this->birth_date;
    $user->type = $this->type;
    $user->external_type = $this->external_type;
    $user->status = $this->status;
    $user->region_id = $this->region_id;
    $user->barangay_id = $this->barangay_id;
    $user->province_id = $this->province_id;
    $user->city_municipal_id = $this->city_municipal_id;

    return $user->save() ? $user : null;
}
}
```

Where did I get wrong here? It is confusing I think that there's no wrong in my code because I followed the proper installation setup of Yii2 Advanced App.

Login Model

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: First of all, **proper installation of Yii2** have **nothing to do** with your code mistakes. Second - you pasted here `signup()` function only, so how can we solve your problem if you ask about `login()`?

Comment: Because when you signup the yii2 makes the user already logged in right? But after signing up it redirects me to the index page and the user isn't logged in. I've tried using the default user table using the yii migration and it works fine but when I use my own user table it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I don't see logging user after signing up in your code. Update your question with proper code, at this moment we can't help you.

Comment: I think thats the code I can only give, I only customised the SignupForm model attributes according to the user table columns. Thanks anyways

Comment: add the singup/register function from your controller

Answer (score 3):

check your user table in phpmyadmin, look at the status column, if this value not equal 10, you can change with 10.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have'nt added the action for the registration or signup, but the point where you are calling the `$model->signup()` function from the model you must check it inside the `if` statement and then add a call to `\Yii::$app->user->login($userModel);` inside, it will log you in after signup.

Your `signup()` function returns the user model object after inserting the user in the table.

See below code sample

```
if(($userModel=$model->signUp())!==null){
   \Yii::$app->user->login($userModel);
}
```

Hope it helps you out

Comment: Actually it is already in the SiteController https://pastebin.com/NBJuse8X

Comment: @noobkoder can you add the `$user->setPassword();` function although i can see the password is hashed in the table, and when you are redirected to the login page after signup does it displays the wrong username/password message? try adding the `var_dump($this->validate())` and `print_r($this->attributes)` inside the `login()` function and see what it prints.

Comment: After signup it redirects me to the index page but the user is not logged in, but if i try to logged in it says the credentials are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your user model class to implement the identity interface?

First declare your class like so

```
class MyUser extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
```

now somewhere in your class you need to implement these methods

```
public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return self::findOne(['id'=>$id]);
    }

    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Validation method not supported as of yet.");
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->auth_key === $authKey;
    }
```

next go to the components section of you /config/web.php and search for the `'user'` component

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\MyUser', //<---Your model class
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
```

I think with that your good to go. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: This one is already automatically at Yii2 Advanced User Class